# Visual Studio 2010 haunted keyboard

Tags: c#, .net-framework, visual-studio, keyboard

It seems the haunted keyboard is back in VS2010 ... after working on a web application for a short while I find that some keys just don't work, or are behaving like certain keys are stuck. This is only in VS, and I am definitely not triggering any keyboard changes in VS or Windows (I have disabled that in Windows) and I have reset my environment settings several times.

Aargh! This is so frustrating ... anyone else getting this problem? Is there a solution?

Comment: Although the software is programming related, this question is not. It should probably be on http://superuser.com

Comment: Roger that ... my apologies I guess I'm grasping at straws

Comment: You may also want to inform us of the addins you have installed. I have R#5 and JustCode and my keyboard has no issues with VS2010

Comment: No add-ins, it is a fresh install as of 2 days ago.

Comment: @Ryan: no need to apologize. It's just outside the scope of SO. :)
Unfortunately, I also doubt that anyone can really give you an answer, unless you hunt down the dev team and force them to debug the issue for you ;)

Comment: Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897335/visual-studio-2010-crash-problems-on-the-keyboard-keys

Comment: Maybe your problem is related to [this bug on msdn](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/536822/vs-2010-keyboard-input-stops-working)? Does your problem go away after you hit *ctrl-tab* two times?

Answer (score 1):

It's your OS language setting.  I had the same problem, and once I deleted my "English (Canada)" language in control panel, VS started working fine again.

Comment: Oh Canada! When will you ever learn.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say i've had this issue or seen other with this issue in Visual Studio 2010 but the following advice seems to have worked for Visual Studio 2005 users:

1. Delete the "Visual Studio 2010" folder in My Documents. (MAKE A BACKUP FIRST THOUGH AS THIS WILL CONTAIN YOUR PROJECT DATA & CODE)
2. Delete the "VisualStudio\10.0" folder in your Local and Roaming AppData folders (AGAIN MAKE BACKUPS)
3. Remove any registry entries to do with Visual Studio 2010 (Visual Studio 10.) - AND ONCE AGAIN MAKE A BACKUP
4. On the menubar click Tools -> Settings -> Import and Export Settings... This will bring up the Import and Export Settings Wizard and you can select the Reset all settings option.

Please keep in mind that I myself havn't actually performed these action myself and that this advice was actually originally given as a temporary fix for the haunted keyboard issue in Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: I think it would be "Import and Export Settings...", not "Important and Export Settings..."

Comment: Thanks, you're right. It was just a typo and i've now edited it.